# How to access two databases, one to input, another to publish simultaneously in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, database

Ok, I am looking to use php to access two databases.

The form posts into database 1 (person), while I have in the form two drop down menus that access a second database named (pulldown) to populate themselves.

So it would look like this.

1. First Name:
2. Last Name:
3. Title (Pull down menu from second database)
4. 401k?:

Now I know to access one database you need to enter in

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
```

How does it work when you need to access two of them?

Now the pull down code isn't an issue, but it is when it is inserted into a form like what I want, how I want to do it, it is.

Can anyone here help?

So what I want is to have access to person and pulldown at the same time, even though data is being pulled from pulldown and entered into person.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: If the databases are at the same host, simply send a query like `mysqli_query("USE db_name");` or create 2 database connection objects.

Comment: You can also format your query to use a 2nd database `SELECT Title FROM db2.table WHERE name = 'Jim'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dbc1 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME1);
$dbc2 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME2);

// ... some code ...

mysqli_query($dbc1,$query1);
mysqli_query($dbc2,$query2);
```

Comment: How will the PHP know which database to take the information from?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php - read the manual about `$link` parameter

Comment: If I could understand php.net more easily I'd not of needed to post here, thanks though.

Comment: `$link` parameter tells mysqli_query which MySQL connection to use. So, if you pass, as in my example, `$dbc1` it will use connection with `DB_NAME1` selected, and, if you pass `$dbc2`, it will use connection with `DB_NAME2` selected. But, in your case, it is may be better to use database prefixes in your queries - `SELECT * FROM  dbname.tablename WHERE somecondition`